# How do I solve an ODE with Tensorflow 2 in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ode

Since Tensorflow 2 there is no more tf.contrib.integrate.odeint. After al lot of searching I could no find any equivalent function in Tensorflow. Did they just remove it, or is it somewhere else? There is obviously a way doing it with scipy and numpy but then I have to convert all the tensors to arrays and back.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) and [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0), it would be moved to a `tensorflow/scientific` repository, but that has not been built. There seems to have been some first effort towards it ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-scientific/), [source](https://github.com/mukeshmithrakumar/scientific)), but it does not seem to be currently under development.